# Существуют ли материалы, показывающие как взаимодействовавть с ОС Windows, используя Qt

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Я бы хотел узнать, как Qt взаимодействует и Windows. К примеру, как узнать, какая программа сейчас запущена.
Если у вас есть учебные материалы, рассказывающие об этом, то оставьте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

только используя winapi
например вот эти

```
BOOL EnumWindows
(
WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc,     // указатель на функцию обратного вызова
LPARAM lParam           // определяемое программой значение
);
```

и

```
BOOL EnumProcesses(
  DWORD   *lpidProcess,
  DWORD   cb,
  LPDWORD lpcbNeeded
);
```